# How to use Accessibility Options in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, accessibility

I am working on a game for blind people. Accessibility doesn't work for me for some buttons.

The buttons are generated randomly and music is played when the user clicks the button.

My code for creating a button.

```
UIButton* button=[[UIButton alloc] init];
[button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[button layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
button.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 90);
button.hidden=YES;
[button setAccessibilityHint:nil];
[button setAccessibilityLabel:nil];
```

Whenever a button is selected the voice over for the button is called. How to disable the voice over for the button.

Help me with following problems

1) I am unable to select few buttons 
2) Disable voice over for the buttons.

*The game works fine without accessibility options.

Comment: I would *love* to help you build an accessible game, but you haven't provided enough details. Please describe a specific problem so we can guide you.

Also, assuming you're developing an iOS app, be sure to read the [Accessibility Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

try [button setAccessibilityElement:false]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).